# How to compare the "Betterness" of Embedding based on changed parameters in Gensim Word2Vec

Tags: deep-learning, nlp, gensim, word2vec, word-embedding

**TL;DR**: How to compare the **betterness** of two `Word2Vec` Embedding which have different set of parameters?

I am using `Gensim` to train my data on a Vocab of around 2 Million sentences and a vocab of 200K words from scratch. Since the loss is given at the end of training, I found some answers which tell you to get the difference between the last time's loss vs the current loss. So I adapted the code and used it for me. I am trying to get the best model based on the Minimum loss. I am using [Optuna for Parameter Tuning](https://github.com/optuna/optuna) or say `GridSearch`. For any tweaked parameters, I am saving my model where it gives me the least loss up until now using a `Callback`.

I plan on using these Embedding with my Classification model. But training the Embedding along with the model will we hell of a task because:

1. Both of them are time consuming
2. `Gensim` works faster with Multiprocessors ( I have 8) than on GPUs ( It does not have that kind of support) but mu Model works on GPU

How can I get something that tells me the **betterness** of Embedding on my data? Below is the code I am using

```
from gensim.models import Word2Vec, FastText
from gensim.models.callbacks import CallbackAny2Vec


class LossCallback(CallbackAny2Vec):
    """
    Callback to print loss after each epoch
    """
    def __init__(self):
        self.epoch = 0
        self.min_loss = np.inf
        self.loss_previous_step = np.inf

    def on_epoch_end(self, model):
        total_loss = model.get_latest_training_loss()
        current_loss = (total_loss - self.loss_previous_step) if self.epoch > 0 else total_loss
        
        if current_loss < self.min_loss:
            self.min_loss = current_loss
            print('Minimum Loss. Saving Model')
            model.save(f'word2vec_{round(current_loss,2)}_loss.model')
            
        if current_loss < self.loss_previous_step :
            print(f"Loss Decreased from {self.loss_previous_step} to {current_loss} in Epoch {self.epoch}")
            
        self.epoch += 1
        self.loss_previous_step = current_loss
              
# Below code is in a Gris Search such as eopchs, window, loss etc etc

def tune(trial):
    
    vector_size = trial.suggest_int('vector_size', 32, 128)
    alpha = trial.suggest_uniform('alpha', 1e-3, 1e-1)
    window = trial.suggest_int('window', 3,9)
    min_count = trial.suggest_int('min_count', 2,10)
    sg = trial.suggest_categorical('hs', [0,1],)
    hs = trial.suggest_categorical('sg', [0,1],)
    negative = trial.suggest_int('negative', 0,20)
    cbow_mean = trial.suggest_categorical('cbow_mean',[0,1],)
    ns_exponent = trial.suggest_float('ns_exponent', 0.4,0.9)
    sample = trial.suggest_uniform('sample',1e-5, 1e-1)
    epochs = trial.suggest_int('epochs', 5, 100)

                                        
    w2v = Word2Vec(sentences = data, workers = 6, epochs = epochs, seed = SEED,
                  vector_size = vector_size, alpha = alpha, window = window, min_count = min_count, sg = sg, hs = hs, negative = negative, cbow_mean = cbow_mean, 
                  sample = sample, ns_exponent = ns_exponent)
    
    w2v.build_vocab(corpus_iterable = data)
    w2v.train(data,epochs = w2v.epochs,total_examples = w2v.corpus_count, total_words = w2v.corpus_total_words, compute_loss = True, callbacks=[LossCallback()])
    
    return w2v.get_latest_training_loss()


direction = 'minimize'
name = 'Word2Vec'
study = optuna.create_study(direction=direction,study_name=name, storage = f"sqlite:///fine_tune_emb/{name}.db", load_if_exists=True)
study.optimize(tune, n_trials=50)
```

Answer (score 0):

The model's internal loss, that it is using for its own internal optimization, is the wrong target for downstream applications.

For example, expanding a model's size will almost always decrease its epoch loss. It will have more internal state with which to essentially 'memorize' aspects of the training data, including idiosyncratic aspects of the training data that don't generalize to usefulness elsewhere. But eventually this decreases performance on any interesting downstream tasks: 'overfitting'. That is: preferring the model with the lowest internal loss is almost guaranteed to steer you wrong.

There is no one set of word-embeddings that's best for every purpose. If you want to optimize your training parameters, you should develop (& continually expand/improve) a way to score any set of word-vectors against some repeatable evaluation that's specific to your needs.

One of the evaluations used in the original word2vec papers was how well the word-vectors could be used to solve language analogy problems, like "WORD_A is to WORD_B as WORD_C is to **?**". You can use this too – Gensim includes methods to run this against word-vectors, with either the exact set of questions used in the word2vec papers, or others you could find elsewhere or create yourself. See for example the `KeyedVectors.evaluate_word_analogies()` method:

https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/keyedvectors.html#gensim.models.keyedvectors.KeyedVectors.evaluate_word_analogies

But, word vectors that are the best at this contrived task may not be the best for other tasks, like similar-information-retrieval or various kinds of classifiers.

As one example of the dimensions on which paramaeter choices can skew word-vectors to be better or worse for certain tasks, the paper '[Dependency-Based Word Embeddings](https://www.semanticscholar.org/paper/Dependency-Based-Word-Embeddings-Levy-Goldberg/0183b3e9d84c15c7048e6c2149ed86257ccdc6cb)' by Levy & Goldberg observed that smaller windows tend to place words near others that are direct syntactic replacements for each other, while larger windows tend to place words near each other which are used in the discussions of the same topics/domains. (See especially their table showing neighbors for 'hogwarts' or 'florida': are they other words of the same category – other schools, or other states? – or of constituents/related-entities – cities or characters?)